# how can i easily format this .xml into every node being under one tag?

Tags: xml

```
    <Variables Name="" Date="2011/06/06 13:09:38">
    <yo>http://www.teamliquid.net/video/streams/Competo</yo>
    <name>Competo</name>
    <word>434</word>
</Variables>
<Variables Name="" Date="2011/06/06 13:09:39">
    <yo>http://www.teamliquid.net/video/streams/Rmdx</yo>
    <name>Rmdx</name>
    <word>66</word>
</Variables>
```

i wish to get all nodes under one tag.. not sure how i would go about it.

Comment: Add a root element ? `<root><variables />.. <variables /></root>`

Comment: Not really sure what you mean - what are you trying to achieve?  The XML there seems pretty reasonable to me...

Comment: @Handcock, the xml is not well-formed; e.g. only one element at the root.

Comment: You could communicate your requirements more clearly if you learnt the proper jargon. "Nodes" exist only in the tree view of XML, "tags" exist only in the lexical (angle-bracket) view, so your question appears very muddled. If you don't know the right words to use, just show us what output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the easiest way is to edit the xml file.  Add a `<root>` at the beginning of the file and `</root>` at the end.

A more general method has been described by Marrow at http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/browse_thread/thread/df9b1f1091aeabf0/e7f384763756affb?q=XML+staticinc+appending&pli=1

The idea here is that we have another file that contains the root and includes the real file.  If the real file is named `variables.xml` then then the root file would contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE staticinc [ 
   <!ENTITY variables SYSTEM "variables.xml"> 
]> 
<root> 
<!-- include the non-well formed XML --> 
  &variables; 
</root>
```

Comment: Another approach is to use (unparsed) CDATA section to encapsulate non-well formed XML within document.